# MSRI Workshop videos and lecture notes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I am referring to MSRI workshop ["Introductory Workshop on Algebraic Stacks, Intersection Theory, and Non-Abelian Hodge Theory"](http://www.msri.org/workshops/137).

There are videos and lecture notes available which can be seen on clicking "Show Schedule, Notes/Handouts & Videos". These are of poor quality, both videos and lecture notes (these are in  .jpg format, once you zoom you can not read anything).

Is there any other place where I can find lecture notes and videos for this workshop?

Comment: Did you contact with the Conference officials about this problem?

Comment: I did not, I have no hope to get a reply from them :) @Amin235 It was long back in 2002 :)

Comment: My recollection is that one of the organizers was William Fulton.  You might contact him.

Comment: @JasonStarr Yes, William Fulton, Ludmil Katzarkov, and Tony Pantev
 are organisers... As you said, I can contact three of them. My email might miss in dozens of mails they receive each day... I will write them an email nevertheless...

Comment: Is there a specific lecture for which you want the notes?

Comment: I am trying to understand cohomology of stacks from Kai Behrend's notes https://www.math.ubc.ca/~behrend/CohSta-1.pdf In last page (References), it is said that there is a video in msri web page... I was thinking it might make it better to learn from video also @JasonStarr

Comment: I used to have lecture notes from those lectures, but now I am having trouble finding them.

Comment: @JasonStarr I am glad you searched for it... :)  please let me know in case you find it sometime in future... :)